# Angular2 , Create Model on runtime

Tags: angular, class, model, runtime

Im newbie angular2, is there a way to create model ( or class) in run time.

The standard technique is declare it in separate files like Hero.ts, Customer.ts, Salesman.ts etc etc

But since the nature of the application, the database structure it self is often to change.

Our strategy to using WebAPI to get model/class structure in string JSON format and based on the downloaded JSON string to created it in run time.

How we could accomplished in TypeScript ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider not using models? Parse/construct the object yourself in the http response.

Comment: how to "Parse/construct the object"  please any direction

Comment: btw atm , im using any in http.get, but im stuck how to 2-ways-binding it, and the rest POST/PUT/DELETE. Any help how to "Parse/construct the object myself in the http response" please

Comment: well... using Angular's HttpClient, `this.http.get(url)` you can get the JSON response (as an observable). If you want models for pure data manipulation you can simply use this plain JS object in your code, without the TS restrictions and conveniences. Why do you really _need_ to wrap your data in a model?

Comment: If you have 200+ tables, I don't understand why you "need" models. Can you post some code?

Comment: sorry, im very new using angular or angularJS, how to "you can simply use this plain JS object in your code, without the TS restrictions and conveniences" ?

Comment: regarding "Why do you really need to wrap your data in a model?" I follow the example in www.angular.io, tours-of-heroes, using template-driven form, the examples from start till end using model/interface. You could direct me to examples/link how to accomplish data manipulation with plain JS object ? the server WebAPI is REST

Comment: If you don't need a model (large database, fast table/api changes), don't need Typescript's auto type-checking, just use plain js objects. I've posted an answer below. Comment if you have more questions and I'll do the best I can to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your database structure changes often? Sounds exciting. :) I would create an interface for every model like you mentioned, but mark the properties as optional:

```
export class Hero {
  name: string;
  age?: string;
  sex?: string;
}
```

Then, you can just get the objects from your HTTP response and say that they are of type Hero.

Comment: hmmm, this could do the trick, but total we have 200+ tables, around >1000+ fields

Comment: When I had the same situation I just dropped the response into a tool which could generate a typescript interface from the response JSON. There are many tools for this, also there is a [VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=topporo.typescript-interface-generator).

The other time, I used a Maven plugin which could generate TypeScript interfaces from our Java Rest API. I assume you can find something like this for any language.

Comment: thank you for your information,  we could generate typescript interface directly from the database using tsql too (both client+server webapi we develop ourself) , and copy & paste it into .ts file. But the issue is we do not want to do this every time the database structure changes. Sorry for making my self not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... it's actually at the beginning of the tour-of-heroes documentation, *before* type-checking. Link: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data

Type-checking isn't *required*. It's just recommended.

## A demo

Manipulating JSON objects:

### Using observables (asynchronous)

a.service.ts

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://something.com/api'); // Returns an observable
  }
}
```

a.component.ts

```typescript
export class AComponent {
  constructor(private service: AService) { }

  doSomething() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      // do things here
    });
  }
}
```

### Using promises and async/await (synchronous)

If the request is a one-time request and you don't need to manipulate data in the observable, you can use Promises and async/await to edit raw JS object data:

a.service.ts

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://something.com/api').toPromise(); // Returns a promise
  }
}
```

a.component.ts

```typescript
export class AComponent {
  constructor(private service: AService) { }

  async doSomething() {
    const data = await this.service.getData();
    // do things here
  }
}
```

Comment: The Getdata is ok, after got it from Http.Get using whatever/no type,  we can show it directly into Html. But now how to make the result from Http.Get "Bindable" , Edit and post it back ?

Comment: This is my modif Get from examples  :   

getHero(id: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:5832/api/heroes/')
    );

But......
  addHero (hero: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:5832/api/heroes', hero, httpOptions)
    )   
  }

did not works.......

Comment: Does your server API accept both get and post requests? Can you provide a Stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, default 5 request, 1. GetRows for return multi rows, 2. GetRow for return 1 row, 3. Add run POST(insert),  4. Update run PUT, dan 5. Delete run Delete

Comment: Im still learning how to use Stackblitz, post my code into cloud (actually first time i hear that :) )

Comment: Okay, post a Stackblitz and I'll try my best to help. You might need to post some server code and/or http responses; if GET works but POST doesn't it might be because of your server config. The more info the better.